# Deliver poisoned vodka to Knight

Tags: hitman-2016

For the mission "The Final Test" in Hitman (2016), is there a way to deliver a poisoned vodka to Knight?

I know where the rat poison and the vodka are located, but how do I blend them and deliver it to Knight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the vodka and the poison up to the Comandante's office, and put the vodka on the table near the glasses.  Then poison the glasses, and Knight will pour the vodka into the glass and drink both.

There's a few pictures and a partial walkthrough [on this page](http://www.gamesradar.com/hitman-challenges-guide/?page=2).

Comment: Wow... the game is 3 days old and they already have visual wt.